# Reallocating pointers to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, realloc

I'm having an issue understanding this, my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct mee test;
typedef struct aa fill;

struct aa {
    int c;
    fill *point;

};
struct mee {
    char name;
    fill **a;
    int b;
};
static fill **store;
static fill *talloc(int tsize);
static int mem;
static int ptr;
static fill *talloc(int tsize)
{   int temp;
    temp = ptr;
    ptr++;
    mem = mem + tsize;
    store = realloc(store, mem*sizeof(fill));
    store[temp] = malloc(sizeof(fill));
    return store[temp];
}

int main() {
    test *t;
        t = malloc(sizeof(test));
    t->a = malloc(sizeof(fill *)*10);
        printf("where\n");

    for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {        
        t->a[i] = talloc(1);
    }
    printf("%d\n", store[9]->c); //Problem here
    return 0;
}
```

excuse the terrible names, just some test code for a larger project. This code compiles and runs fine. if I set the code:

```
printf("%d\n", store[9]->c);
```

store[0-7] I get 0 as the output, though why does 8-9 give me some gibberish negative number? I'm assuming its a loss it the pointer somewhere.
How can I correct this?

For some background, this is to store pointers to struct in a array so I can free them a lot easier later.

Comment: `store[9]->c` isn't initialized. also `store = realloc(store, mem*sizeof(fill));` --> `store = realloc(store, mem*sizeof(fill*));`

Comment: In `talloc()`, you have: `int temp;
    temp = ptr;
    ptr++;` —— you could have `int temp = ptr++;`.  It's not a part of your problem, but it is a bit verbose.

Comment: Note that `store = realloc(store, mem*sizeof(fill));` is an incipient memory leak if the reallocation fails (your code isn't testing any of the memory allocations, which is a little dubious).  What BLUEPIXY said is important; the memory allocated by `malloc()` is not initialized, and your code doesn't initialize it, so what you get is indeterminate — not guaranteed to be zero, or positive, or negative, or anything in particular.  Initialize allocated memory — or use `calloc()` to zero it on allocation (but `realloc()` never initializes the extra allocated memory).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added safeguards to catch any failures, an initialized my allocations. Thanks for the heads up. - also, the reason for the break up of code, my lecturer encourages that we do not initialized and associate values together in the same line, it's a bit annoying, I know.

Comment: Regarding the "background": For the most cases I'd say: don't. Wrap your allocations in suitable functions. Don't try to reinvent some primitive form of garbage collection (unless for personal education).